# Rails + Rspec: var.should == "5", or var.should == var2.value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a simple question about practices with Rspec testing. I am trying to test that the value of one of the hash keys is a certain value. However, this value comes from another object. So do I test equivalence of

```
describe "#params_for_authorization_request" do
  let(:credit_card) { {"cc_acct"=>"5105105105105100", "cc_expmm"=>"12", "cc_expyy"=>"2015", "cc_cvv" => "123"} }
  let(:paypal) { Paypal.new(credit_card: credit_card) }

  it "returns a hash with a ACCT key" do
    paypal.params_for_authorization_request["ACCT"].should == "5105105105105100"
  end
```

So should this line:

```
  it "returns a hash with a ACCT key" do
    paypal.params_for_authorization_request["ACCT"].should == "5105105105105100"
  end
```

be turned into this line?

```
  it "returns a hash with a ACCT key" do
    paypal.params_for_authorization_request["ACCT"].should == credit_card["cc_acct"]
  end
```

or even this?

```
  it "returns a hash with a ACCT key" do
    paypal.params_for_authorization_request["ACCT"].should == paypal.credit_card["cc_acct"]
  end
```

What's the general consensus on this?

Comment: I vote for the first alternative with credit_card[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer this one:

```
it "returns a hash with a ACCT key" do
  paypal.params_for_authorization_request["ACCT"].should == credit_card["cc_acct"]
end
```

However, if you're using rspec 2.11 or above, then probably this is the better approach:

```
it "returns a hash with a ACCT key" do
  expect(paypal.params_for_authorization_request["ACCT"]).to eq(credit_card["cc_acct"])
end
```

Reference: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax

Comment: Thanks for the tip at the end. So should I stop using `.should` in general?