# Using expect and should in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

There is the following RSpec code:

```
it 'is not valid if name is not present' do
    @car.name = nil
    expect(@car).to be_invalid
end
```

I read "Testing with RSpec" by Aaron Sumner now, and he writes about new styles in RSpec. Earlier I wrote the following code:

```
it 'is not valid if name is not present' do
    @car.name = nil
    it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

Please, tell me, do I right? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for here? Can you please explain what's your confusion or question?

Comment: I want to know if my specs have a good style?

Comment: It is. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437817/rails-rspec-var-should-5-or-var-should-var2-value/21438017#21438017

Answer (score 13):

I think this is a good example

```
describe "Car"
  describe '#valid?' do
    context 'when its name is nil' do
      let(:car) { FactoryGirl.create(:car, :name => nil) }

      it 'is not valid' do 
        expect(car).to_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Find more about better specs [here](http://betterspecs.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`let` API](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) instead of the using `@car`, so that you won't risk changing the state from test to test, in a way which might break tests in unpredictable manner.

The `it` [one-liner](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax) refers to the `subject` so to make your second style work it should look like that:

```
describe '#valid?' do
  let(:car) do
    # make your car here
  end

  subject { car } # <- this is the important line to make it work...

  before do
    car.name = nil
  end

  it { should_not be_valid }
end
```